# What's the point in using .winmd library if I still need the .dll and .pri file?

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015, shared-libraries, winmd

I wanted to use the winfbsdk (see [here](http://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb/)) which is an SDK for using Facebook inside UWP (Universal Windows Apps (Windows 10)). But it seems that the `.winmd` file that is built is not enough to be able to use this library. I can do one of the following:

1. Reference the whole project as is stated in the documentation.

or

2. Reference the `.winmd` file but also copy the generated `.DLL` + `.pri` file.

Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

These files are used at different times.  The .winmd file contains the type information for the library.  It is used by IntelliSense when you edit your code, providing auto-completion.  And used by the compiler, it performs syntax checking on your code.

The .dll and .pri file are necessary later.  When the app package for your project is built.  Which includes your program as well as all of its dependencies.  An app package provides a single download from the store and ensures that everything that the user needs to run your program is delivered to his machine.  It is a very strong DLL Hell counter-measure, your program isn't going to fall over because the user's machine is missing the DLL or has the wrong version of it.